# How does the Silverlight 3 VirtualizingStackPanel work?

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-3.0

What are the actual conditions that make the Silverlight 3 VirtualizingStackPanel virtualise its content?

For example is it only when elements are off screen regardless of what container it is in or does the VirtualizingStackPanel have to be in a ScrollViewer before it starts applying the virtualisation?

I ask this because the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.virtualizingstackpanel%28VS.95%29.aspx) does not give much information, there also seems to be very little useful information on the web and I would like to have a deeper knowledge of how it works!

Thanks people,

Adam

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the VirtualizingStackPanel is to allow it to only show items that are visible. Its normally used inside another container as its ItemsContainer:

```
<ListBox>
  <ListBox.ItemsContainer>
    <VirtualizingStackPanel />
  </ListBox.ItemsContainer>
</ListBox>
```

(Which is the default now)

Comment: Hi Shawn,

Thanks for responding. I was wondering exactly how it knows things are not currently displayed on screen and therefore are not drawn?

Any ideas or links?

Thank you,


Adam